# "string extends S" in Typescript template string conditional

Tags: typescript

In the [original PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40336) to implement template strings, Hejlsberg gives an example for a split type function:

```
type Split<S extends string, D extends string> =
    string extends S ? string[] :
    S extends '' ? [] :
    S extends `${infer T}${D}${infer U}` ? [T, ...Split<U, D>] :
    [S];
```

What is the purpose of the constraint `string extends S`? Is that simply to allow for `type T = Split<string>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is its purpose. Without the check, all the conditionals would evaluate to the false-branch which would give the result `[string]` if `string` was given for `S`.

This is fine as far  as the conditional type is concerned as it was not able to split the string. But in TypeScript, we often try to model the runtime behaviour of JavaScript. And given an unknown `string`, we simply don't know if it can or can not be split into multiple strings at runtime. That's why we need to add this *conservative* check to return `string[]` instead.

Comment: Enhance the answer with an example of what would happen without the `string extends S` to really drive the point home :)